# select the last iFrame in the body

Tags: css, iframe

Imagine I have

```
<body>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

I want to select the last one.

I tried `body:last-child` but it did not work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Read the documentation again. You want body iframe:last-child{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
iframe:last-of-type { ... }
```